# Button, appear after duplicate is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to ensure only a plus button is showing to add a duplicate field set if theres only one, but add the remove button once a duplicate is created, I have an idea on how to do this by assigning a number value to each duplicate field set created but I cant seem to get it to work, any advice or pointed in the right direction would be great.

Below is the code at this current moment which will replicate the field set once the button is clicked:

```
               $('body').on("click ", '.glyphicon-plus-sign', function() {
                console.log("here ");
                prevInput = $(this);
                count = $(prevInput).attr('data-count=')||0;
                countIncremented = count++;
                br = '<br/><br/>';                  
                $($(this).parent()).clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
```

I know I need to assign a value to each field set in such a manner as this:

```
newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      
        newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum);
```

But cant get it to work or refactor it to get it to work for my own application.

JSFiddle Link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/23/)

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: Js fiddle added to the Question as requested

Comment: Anyone able to advise me on the functionality needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all fieldsets in the page, then you will be able to know how much you got of them.

```
var count_element = $('.fieldset').length;

if (count_element > 1)
    $("#id-of-button").show();  
else
    $("#id-of-button").hide();
```